# Factory Resetting My Device

Tags: factory-reset, huawei-g610s

I'm planning to factory reset my device soon. So I wanted to know how do I transfer my notes to the SD Card. I don't want to lose them. Can someone please provide a meaningful tutorial on the matter. Please feel free to include methods to transfer other stuff as well.

Comment: This could very well vary based on the note-taking app you're using. It would be helpful if you could specify that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the app send to SD when I had my MYTouch and I transferred my photos, apps, notes to my note3. Everything was on my SD card as long as you don't have an emulated file you are fine.  once I got an emulated file on my note3 nothing transferred to the next one. You can open a dropbox account and an evernote account. Once you do the reset you download the apps and you sign into those apps and you have your photos and your notes.. another photo saving place is myphotos.com.. good luck with the reset :/